# Transitive Animation From Android 2.2 to latest release

Tags: android

I want to use animation compatible with android version 2.2 to 4.1.2. i tried using xml animation but it does not do not work under ginderbread. can someone tell me if there exist animation from left to right and right to left compatible with all android version and why ?

enter.xml

```
     android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"

      android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"

     android:duration="2000"/>
```

leave.xml

```
     android:shareInterpolator="false">

  <translate

   android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"

   android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"

   android:duration="2000" />
```

i called it with this method but it isn't compabible with gingerbread

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.leave,R.anim.enter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this:

anim_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="50%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

I used it to translate fragments. I tested it on api 2.x and on 4.x as well.

Comment: will it work on transiting between two activities ? i tested it but there is no result

Comment: It should. You need to create second animation, which will be the opposite of this one. And use a methot that you tried to use before: overridePendingTransition().

Comment: hi, i did this for anim_right.xml ,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="50%p" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set> but it doesn't work